# How to solve error: a spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm developing wrapper class, which can call inner instance's method with string argument.

The whole code is like below.

```
class Inner {
  public prop1: string = 'publicProp';
  private prop2: string = 'privateProp';

  method1(param1: string) {
    console.log(`${param1}`);
  }
  method2(param1: number, param2: number) {
    console.log(`${param1}, ${param2}`);
  }
}
```

This class is original class have core functions.

```
type Fn = (...args: any) => any;
```

This is type needed in below

```
class Outer {
  private inner = new Inner();

  // I want proxy's second parameter's type will be changed according to first parameter's value
  public proxy<
    // F type is callable member's key
    F extends keyof {
      [K in keyof Inner as Inner[K] extends Fn ? K : never]: any;
    },
    // P type will be changed according to first argument type.
    P extends Parameters<Inner[F]>,
  >(name: F, ...args: P) {
    const fn = this.inner[name];
    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
      // This is right pain point!!
      // TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
      fn(...args);
    }
  }
}
```

The part of `fn(...args)` keeps showing error like above. I think, `args` should be inferred as tuple because we let the compiler know `args`'s type will be extended by `Parameter<Inner[F]>`. How can I fix it?

```
const outer = new Outer().proxy;
// IDE can infer parameter's type from second parameter
outer('method1', 'stringArg');
outer('method2', 1, 2);
```

Another pain point is that the IDE can infer the parameter types according to first argument. (The real snapshot of IDE is attached below)

[image]

Thanks in advance your answer! :)